# Smart Lock Timeout

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, smart-lock

With my MotoX (pre-Lolipop) I could unlock my phone via the Motorola Skip app and a trusted NFC device.  Post-Lolipop, the Skip app no longer works, but the NFC unlocking is now built in.

The problem is that every 4 hours the trust is expired and I have to unlock with my password again.  Is there any way to change the 4 hour timeout or disable it altogether?